# How ETSY sellers manage stock of configurable products?

Tags: inventory-management, etsy

I want to integrate **ETSY** on my inventory management project but after little research I got to know that it didn't manage stock of variants for configurable product. It manages stock of overall product, not of its particular variant.

Now I am very curious how etsy seller manage stock particular variant?

Is there any way I can manage stock of my particular variant in etsy?

Comment: As of 2017, this does indeed work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot manage stock for a particular variant.

If it is really important you don't sell more than you have on stock (lots of time to make or impossible to reproduce) then it's best to make a different listing - this also has the advantage of SEO (you can add different keywords from the other variant).